# Cucumber/Javascript - Negative Testing an API failing because it returns 401

Tags: javascript, cucumber, gherkin

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

I have this test case:

- Given I call getAuthToken with "Id", "Secret" and "Audience"
- Then I should receive 401 response
- And error as "access_denied"

Examples

| ClientId | ClientSecret | Audience |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | audience |
|  | 1 | audience |
|  |  | audience |

I'm purposefully trying to return a 401 response code by missing out values as they are mandatory to get a 200. Naturally, this does produce the 401 as expected but Cucumber is seeing this as a fail so decides not to proceed to the next step.

Is it possible to continue on any response code?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But with no context it's difficult to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton - I've edited my original question - is that better?